# How to fetch (using Fetch API) only headers in Javascript, not the whole content?

Tags: javascript, http-headers, fetch-api

Here I have this [sample fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/YinCognito/n7c63r7u/), where I try to get **only** the `content-type` header from a large image, using both `XMLHttpRequest()` and `fetch()` in Javascript. If you run the fiddle with Chrome's Developer Tools / Network tab (or similar tools in other browsers) open, you'll see that while the `XMLHttpRequest()` method gets only the 600 B where the headers are located, the `fetch()` method gets the whole 7.8 MB image, despite my code only needing the `content-type` headers.

How can I get just those few bytes needed for the headers (instead of the whole content) using the Fetch APi's `fetch()`?

Note: I am interested in this, because apparently, if I try to get the headers of all the links of a regular Google page, the `XMLHttpRequest()` method logs me out and sometimes changes my language as well, while the `fetch()` method does not. I assume this is because the former sends the credentials / cookies / etc., while the latter is more 'restrictive' by default...

Answer (score 58, accepted):

You need to specify the method type of `HEAD`:

```
fetch(url, {method: 'HEAD'})
```

[See updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/n7c63r7u/2/)